# Derivative On Python

Tags: python, math, derivative

Hi I make some derivative Program on Python, but the result isn't same as what i expected,

This is the result as what i want to be :

```
f(x) = x^2 - 8x + 25
f'(x) = 2x -8
    0 = 2x - 8
    8 = 2x
    4 = x
    x = 4
```

i want x to be equal to 4

and here's the code :

```
import sympy as sp     

from sympy import *

p = 8
m = 25

f = x**2 - p*x + m
f_prime = f.diff(x)

f = lambdify(x, f) 
f_prime = lambdify(x, f_prime)

f_prime(2)
```

the result is -4

how to solve this problem?

Thankyou

Comment: One thing that's weird is that your first snippet contains two completely separate sections of code, one using `sympy` the other `scipy`, with an unused `numpy` import. Please clean that up, this should be a [mcve].

Comment: f_prime(2) = 2 (2) - 8 = 4 - 8 = -4. Were you looking to do ```solve(f_prime(x), x)```?

Comment: @fdireito Thank you, but I don't have any idea how this code run, because I don't have any experience with python. But I want the result is equal to 4 not -4, should i add 8 after 8?

Comment: Oh ok. Then this isn't really Python. This is Maths. You want f'(x) = 0, but you are doing f'(2).

Comment: `from sympy import Eq, solve` and `res = solve(Eq(f.diff(x), 0))`.  `lambdify` is not needed here.  Giving the lambdified function the same name as the sympy expression creates unnecessary confusion.

Comment: I tried it, now how to print the result?, because i tried print(res), but it will run error @JohanC

Comment: Which error? Did you define `x`? E.g. `x = Symbols(x)`? `from sympy import Eq, solve from sympy.abc import x; p = 8; m = 25; f = x ** 2 - p * x + m; f_prime = f.diff(x); print(solve(Eq(f_prime, 0)))` should print `[4]` (it's a list, as in theory there can be multiple solutions to an equation).

Comment: Not reproducible. This code gives an error `File "diff.py", line 8, in <module>
    f = x**2 - p*x + m
NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry that was my fault, i wrote print(res) not print(solve(Eq(f_prime, 0))) , sorry about that, and Thank you for helping me @JohanC

Comment: Yap, it's true, but right now the problem is solved, Thanks @YuriGinsburg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `x` as a symbolic variable (otherwise code will not compile), lambdify f_prime and solve the equation `f_prime(x) = 0`

```
from sympy import *

p = 8
m = 25

x = symbols('x')

f = x**2 - p*x + m
f_prime = f.diff(x)
print (f_prime)

f_prime = lambdify(x, f_prime)
print(solve(f_prime(x))[0])

2*x - 8
4
```

Comment: Thanks it works